# How to implement customized <input type="reset" />?

Tags: html, reset

When onmouseover,it should look like

```
<input type="image" src="1.jpg" />
```

When onmouseout,it should look like

```
<input type="image" src="2.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the `<input type=reset>` and using Javascript hide it, create an `<a>` element and style it as much as I please, attach an event handler on `click` to the anchor to trigger the reset, and use CSS `:hover` on the anchor so the background image changes. Users without Javascript will see the regular ole' reset button.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your CSS the proper rules for `:hover`; It should work on everything but IE, which doesn't support hover in any element.

Comment: I'm asking HOW to change look of reset control,because it doesn't support something like src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but like Tordek, I would suggest using CSS and :hover

Here's the CSS:

```
.myButton{
  background:url("2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background:url("1.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="myButton" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about changing the presentation of the reset button itself, make it invisible. Make your own reset button, represented by a link with a hash for a href, and have it invoke the rest button when clicked:

```
<a href="#" class="resetPush">
  <span>Reset</span>
</a>
```

Coupled with the following javascript:

```
$("input[type='reset']").hide();
$("a.resetPush").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("input[type='reset']").trigger("click");
});
```

And as for the rollover effect of the link, css can handle that for you:

```
a.resetPush span { display:none; }
a.resetPush      { display:block; width:100px; height:25px;
                   background: url("slider.jpg") left top no-repeat; }
a.resetPush:hover{ background-position: left bottom; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<input type="image">` is merely meant to present some kind of a **map** wherein the end-user would be able to point specific locations in.

But you don't want to do that. You just want a button with a **background** image. I would thus suggest to replace it by an `<input type="reset">` with a CSS `background-image` which is set to `url(path/to/your/image.png)`. You can then add some Javascript ([jQuery](http://jquery.com) maybe? there's a [hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) function) which changes the CSS class on mouseover and mouseout. For example:

```
$("#buttonid").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
);
```

with CSS

```
#buttonid {
    background: url(path/to/your/image.png);
}
#buttonid.hover {
    background-position: 20px; /* Make use of CSS sprites. */
}
```

(more about CSS sprites [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites))

Some would suggest to use the CSS `:hover` pseudoclass for this, but that doesn't work in all browsers on other elements than `<a>`.